# MongoDB aggregate with event based user time tracking

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

and first off, thank you for reading and maybe coming up with a solution.

Currently I’m trying to figure out how to aggregate and sum event base user datetime events. Let’s assume the stored data looks like the following:

```js
export type TimeTrackingEvents = "start" | "pause" | "resume" | "end";
export interface ITimeTracking {
  user: string;
  event: TimeTrackingEvents;
  timestamp: Date;
}
```

After a users working day we have the following set of data in our DB:

```js
[{
  _id: 5c87f24d15e381003334f26f,
  user: 5c87bb4aad3c21e90aeda6f7,
  timestamp: 2019-03-14T07:00:00.000Z,
  event: 'start'
},
{
  _id: 5c8a5ceea708844edc9e1d31,
  user: 5c87bb4aad3c21e90aeda6f7,
  timestamp: 2019-03-14T08:00:00.000Z,
  event: 'pause'
},
{
  _id: 5c8a5d02a708844edc9e1d33,
  user: 5c87bb4aad3c21e90aeda6f7,
  timestamp: 2019-03-14T09:00:00.000Z,
  event: 'resume'
},
{
  _id: 5c8a5cf9a708844edc9e1d32,
  user: 5c87bb4aad3c21e90aeda6f7,
  timestamp: 2019-03-14T10:00:00.000Z,
  event: 'end',
}];
```

Based on the data the user has been working 2h ours today.
And this leads us the to final question: How do I, based on the datasets given, achieve the following output?

```js
{
  _id: 5c87f24d15e381003334f26f,
  user: 5c87bb4aad3c21e90aeda6f7,
  duration: 2, // this represents the 2 hours the user has been working
}
```

This means that I want to sum event duration “start” to “pause” and “resume” to “end”, without the duration between “pause” and “resume”.

I've been searching here and on the web but couldn't find a proper solution for the aggregation.

This my aggregation so far:

```js
[
  {
    $match: {
      user: userId,
      // only today
      timestamp: {
        $gte: today,
        $lt: tomorrow,
      },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  // above works, insert magic here... ;)
]
```

My MongoDB is on Version 4.

Thank you guys again for your time.
Cheers Toni

**EDIT**

So here's the status quo:
@AnthonyWinzlet Thank you very much. The link you've provided did help!

So ATM I'm at the point that I added the following:

```js
{   
  $addFields: {
    timeOfDay: { // The result from '2019-03-14T10:00:00.000+00:00' is 36.000.000 which equals 10 hours
      $mod: [
        { $toLong: "$timestamp" },
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

I get fields like `timeOfDay:36000000` which represents 10 hours.

What i can't get to work is the `$switch` mentioned by @JonasWilms. The result / "totalTimeInMinutes" represents always 122.400.000 (which 34 hours), even though I convert the ms to a negative value with:

```js
// ...
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "result",
      totalTimeInMinutes: {
        // $sum: { $divide: ["$timeOfDay", 60 * 1000] },
        $sum: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              { case: "end", then: { $multiply: ["$timeOfDay", 1] } },
              { case: "start", then: { $multiply: ["$timeOfDay", -1] } },
              { case: "resume", then: { $multiply: ["$timeOfDay", -1] } },
              { case: "pause", then: { $multiply: ["$timeOfDay", 1] } },
            ],
            default: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
// ...
```

This is because 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 equals 34, but it must be 10 + (-9) + 8 + (-7) which equals 2.

Comment: If I am right user has worked 4 hours today?

Comment: @anthony-winzlet I should've been more precise. I'm talking about the "effective" / net working hours.
This means: 7 to 8 equals 1 hour, 1 hour break (8 to 9) and another hour from 9 to 10 o'clock.

Comment: This will probably help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954793/find-the-total-time-spent-by-an-user-in-mongodb/53954818#53954818

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could group the array into one single object and sum up the times (that assumes that all times match):

```
{
   $group: {
     _id: "result", // you could directly group by user id here
     duration: { $sum: { // in rounded / floored hours
       $switch: { branches: [
          { case: "start", then: { $multiply: [{ $hour: "$timestamp"}, -1] },
          { case: "end", then: { $multiply: [{ $hour: "$timestamp" }, 1] },
          { case: "pause", then: { $multiply: [{ $hour: "$timestamp" }, -1] },
          { case: "resume", then: { $multiply: [{ $hour: "$timestamp" }, 1] }
      ]}
   }}
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, $multiply only supports numeric types, not date.

Comment: @tonait aah, right, well then https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing my head in the right direction.
I'd like the share my final solution. I guess there will be a more elegant version and edge cases haven't been tested yet but it works like this:

```js
[
  {
    $match: {
      // this is just for testing purpose atm
      timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date(today),
        $lt: new Date(tomorrow),
      },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      timeOfDay: { // The result from '2019-03-14T10:00:00.000+00:00' is 36.000.000 which equals 10 hours
        $mod: [
          { $toLong: "$timestamp" },
          1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      timeOfDay: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $in: ["$event", ["start", "resume"]] },
          then: { $multiply: ["$timeOfDay", -1] },
          else: "$timeOfDay",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "result",
      workingMinutesToday: {
        $sum: { $divide: ["$timeOfDay", { $multiply: [60, 1000] }] },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

I'd love to see a more elegant approach from you guys, but I hope this will save someones time

Cheers
Toni